# Sign in as Different User in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I am trying to implement "Sign in as different user" on windows authentication asp.net web site. 
I followed this blog [Sign in as Different User](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=825&cpage=1#comment-7207). Everythig is fine except `Cancel` button. 
When user requested for userid/password dialog box. If I hit `cancel` button. it stays at `Access denied` page.

But I want redirect IIS access denied 401 page. How to do that?

Comment: Use Fiddler to verify that the correct 401 page is transfered from your webserver, and that it's large enough to be shown. Internet Explorer will show built-in messages if the pages served by the webserver is less than 512 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the Application_EndRequest in the global.asax file. A piece of information from the article linked below (not my code):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
if (context.Response.Status.Substring(0,3).Equals("401"))
 {
  context.Response.ClearContent();
  context.Response.Write("<script language="javascript">" + 
                   "self.location='../login.aspx';</script>");
 } 
}
```

Take a [look here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11202/Redirecting-to-custom-401-page-when-quot-Access-de) for the full-article